# when a JRadioButton is clicked it will not print out correct

Tags: java

i am trying to make a code that when pressed by he user it will print out correct but instead of printing out correct it just does nothing. i have researched this topic very clearly but i cannot seem to find the right answer if any body can help me it will be greatly appreciated

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JRadioButtonTest 
{

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JRadioButton Test");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("0.4");
    JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("12");
    JRadioButton button3 = new JRadioButton("37");

    ButtonGroup colorButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    colorButtonGroup.add(button1);
    colorButtonGroup.add(button2);
    colorButtonGroup.add(button3);

    frame.add(new JLabel("what is the density of a piece of rock that is 40 grams and 25cm3"));
    frame.add(button1);
    frame.add(button2);
    frame.add(button3);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    if(button2.isSelected()){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"correct");
      } 
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to add a listener to the button. With your current code, it checks the button as soon as the frame is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you check immediately the state of the radio buttons after you created them. Because of this, you have to press the radio button between the `setVisible(true)` call and the check, which is practically impossible.

What you are looking for are Listeners, these will be executed if specific events happen. 
As example the ItemListener, which is most applicable to your example as it will be executed every time the value of the radio buttons change.

```
button2.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
{
 @Override
 public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
   if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
    // Your selected code here.
   }
   else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
    // Your deselected code here.
   }
 }
}
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the radio button, it's an event happen at run time. The code you have at the end main method is executed ONLY once before the frame is loaded. In order to trigger that function every time you click, you need to register a listener. So, your code would look like this:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class JRadioButtonTest 
    {

      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JRadioButton Test");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("0.4");
        JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("12");
        JRadioButton button3 = new JRadioButton("37");

        ButtonGroup colorButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        colorButtonGroup.add(button1);
        colorButtonGroup.add(button2);
        colorButtonGroup.add(button3);

        frame.add(new JLabel("what is the density of a piece of rock that is 40 grams and 25cm3"));
        frame.add(button1);
        frame.add(button2);
        frame.add(button3);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"correct");

            }
        });
      }
    }
```

Ideally, it's better to write your own implementation of `ActionListener` and register it to all the elements you need. You capture the element using the 'e' object.

Comment: File: C:\Users\EC\JRadioButtonTest.java  [line: 36]
Error: The method addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener) in the type javax.swing.AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionListener(){})
File: C:\Users\EC\JRadioButtonTest.java  [line: 36]
Error: ActionListener cannot be resolved to a type
File: C:\Users\EC\JRadioButtonTest.java  [line: 39]
Error: ActionEvent cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Share your full code! My guess is you are missing the imports

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip to make this easier:

There are some Eclipse Neon packages that allow you to implement a view that will let you enable functions such as that with clicks of a button and allow you to see the project in real time.

help>install package

http://downlods.eclipse.org/releases/neon

Looking through that might be useful to you!